# How to setup Hibernate with Eclipse (Luna) on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, ubuntu, jboss

I am trying to teach myself how to utilize Hibernate. I am working on Ubuntu 14.0.4 using Eclipse Luna. I have come across some tutorials showing how to use hibernate itself but not really a definitive one for how to actually set it up and use it within a project in eclipse.

I am hoping that someone can shed some light on that. As of now I have downloaded hibernate_release_4.3.6 from the official website and I have installed JBoss in eclipse. I was hoping that JBoss would just install the hibernate stuff for me (and maybe it did) but I am still no closer to using it or importing it into a project.

Any guidance on this would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest clone the Wildfly (newest JBoss) examples [repo](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart) and look into [this project](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/hibernate4). The readme file is quite descriptive.

Also you may consider using the [JBoss Developer Studio](https://www.jboss.org/products/devstudio/overview/). It's based on Eclipse and it has support for JBoss technologies. Youtube tutorial how to set up the Hibernate is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlK7XasSbec).